# Not able run Ansible HTPASSWD playbook for creating user's, because FIPS is enabled :-(

Tags: linux, encryption, redhat-enterprise-linux, ansible

I am trying to run a Ansible playbook for adding few user's to  HTPASSWD, Since FIPS(Federal Information Processing Standards) is enabled on it, I am getting error saying FIPS is enabled please disable it but I don't want to disable FIPS, how do I run HTPASSWD module when FIPS is enabled